# Stop event propagation on focus JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm testing keyboard navigation, but as I move on a dropdownlist it index change itself, I mean if it value is A as we focus on it through keyboard it value will become B.

I've used this to stop this but still no luck.

```
 e.preventDefault();
e.cancelBubble = true;
return false;
```

Here is the entire script of navigation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _parent;
var _selectedIndex = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input.flat,select.flat").click(function(){
    
        $("input.flat,select.flat").each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
        });
        
        $(this).addClass('active_ele');
    
    });


    $("select.flat").bind('focus',function (e) {
        
        //e.preventDefault();
        //e.focus();
        //return false;
        //e.cancelBubble = true;
        //return false;
    });
    
    $("input.flat,select.flat").bind('keydown',function (e) {
            
        switch(e.keyCode)
        {
            case 37:
                /////Right
                _parent = $(this).parent().prev();
                
                if(_parent.hasClass('combo'))   ///this is select
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                    nNode = _parent.children("select.flat");
                    nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                    _selectedIndex = nNode[0].selectedIndex;
                    nNode[0].focus();
                    nNode[0].selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
                    
                }
                else if(_parent.hasClass('inputBox'))   ///this is select
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                    nNode = _parent.children("input.flat");
                    nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                    nNode.focus();
                    
                }   
                
            
            break;
            
            case 39:
            //////////Left
            
                _parent = $(this).parent().next();
                
                if(_parent.hasClass('combo'))   ///this is select
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                    nNode = _parent.children("select.flat");
                    nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                    _selectedIndex = nNode[0].selectedIndex;
                    nNode[0].focus();
                    nNode[0].selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
                }
                else if(_parent.hasClass('inputBox'))   ///this is select
                {
                    $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                    nNode = _parent.children("input.flat");
                    nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                    nNode.focus();
                }   
                
                
                break;

            case 40:
                /////Down
                _nNode = $(this).parent();
                _index = _nNode.attr('data');
                
                _index =  parseInt(_index) + 1
                ///td
                _nNode = _nNode.parent()
                    .next()
                    .children(0)[_index];
                
                _nNode = $(_nNode); 
                
                if(_nNode[0])
                {
                    if(_nNode.hasClass('combo'))
                    {   
                        
                        _nNode = _nNode.children("select.flat");
                        _nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                        $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                        _selectedIndex = _nNode[0].selectedIndex;
                        _nNode[0].focus();
                        _nNode[0].selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
                        
                    }
                    else if(_nNode.hasClass('inputBox'))
                    {
                        _nNode = _nNode.children("input.flat");
                        _nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                        $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                        _nNode.focus();
                    }
                }
                
        
                break;

            case 38:
            /////Up
                    _nNode = $(this).parent();
                _index = _nNode.attr('data');
                    _index =  parseInt(_index) + 1
                ///td
                _nNode = _nNode.parent()
                    .prev()
                    .children(0)[_index];
                _nNode = $(_nNode); 
                if(_nNode[0])
                {
                    if(_nNode.hasClass('combo'))
                    {   
                        
                        _nNode = _nNode.children("select.flat");
                        _nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                        $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                        _selectedIndex = _nNode[0].selectedIndex;
                        _nNode[0].focus();
                        _nNode[0].selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
                    }
                    else if(_nNode.hasClass('inputBox'))
                    {
                        _nNode = _nNode.children("input.flat");
                        _nNode.addClass('active_ele');
                        $(this).removeClass('active_ele');
                        _nNode.focus();
                    }
                }
                break;

            case 46:
                $(this).val("");
        }
        
        e.preventDefault();
        e.cancelBubble = true;
        return false;

            
    });
});

</script>
```

Link to the file, please suggest a solution, how to stop this index changing.
[http://69.175.126.242/~develope/younussal/test/test.htm](http://69.175.126.242/%7Edevelope/younussal/test/test.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `e.stopPropagation();`

It is in the JQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: I've placed it at the bottom of the keydown binding event but still index changes as I navigate. and it raise an error on console e.stopPropogation(); is not a function thanks

Comment: Index is still changing, plz check it by saving the above link and append the e.stopPropogation(); at the bottom of the event thank you

Comment: its not working it raise error e.stopPropogation(); is not a function

Comment: Sorry misspelled, the corrected function is `e.stopPropagation();`

Comment: thanks but the index is still changing please check the link and navigate with scroll keys and observe the index changes http://69.175.126.242/~develope/younussal/test/test.htm

Comment: this is really weird... I added the handler to your page before and it was working fine, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered this same problem :

The hack I used was to blur it

```
node.addEventListener('focus',function(){this.blur();},false);
```

Comment: blur doesn't work when I use this code. $("select.flat").bind('focus',function(e){
  
  this.blur();
  return false;});

Comment: I can't navigate from dropdown list to next control

Comment: this is also not working    $("select.flat").bind('focus',function(e){
  
  //alert(_selectedIndex);
  //console.log(this.selectedIndex + ' val: '+this.value  + '    ' +_selectedIndex );
  
  
  this.selectedIndex = _selectedIndex;
  e.preventDefault();
  //e.focus();
  //return false;
  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.stopPropogation();
  return false;
 });

Comment: please check the link http://69.175.126.242/~develope/younussal/test/test.htm index is still changing

Comment: I havent quite understood ur question :(

Comment: Sorry! Plz click on any one control and navigate using scroll keys and observe dropdown value changes when we navigate, I need to stop that value changing. thanks http://69.175.126.242/~develope/younussal/test/test.htm

Answer (score -1):

Use the 'TAB' key to move between controls instead of the arrows key (standard keyboard navigation).

Do not intercept arrow keys, you need them to change the values in the controls (selected items in the select boxes).

The browser and the OS should already do most of the work for you.

Comment: thanks but I need to use arrow keys, and its working, but it change the dropdown value.